# d3.scaleLinear returns NaN the second time it is called

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm fairly new to d3.js and I'm exploring it slowly. So far I've only been trying to create a bar chart on where I load the data from a json file and when I click the bars, it changes the data to another column of the json.

The json file is formatted like this:

```
[
  {
    "ym": "201801",
    "clients": 179,
    "trans": 987,
  },
  {
    "ym": "201802",
    "clients": 178,
    "trans": 334,
  }
]
```

Whenever I load up the page, everything is fine, the chart is loaded up and everything works well. However, when I click on the bars, the axis change, the text changes but the bars do not appear. I checked the console and I have this, multiple times:

```
d3.v4.min.js:2 Error: <rect> attribute y: Expected length, "NaN".
(anonymous) @ d3.v4.min.js:2
d3.v4.min.js:2 Error: <rect> attribute height: Expected length, "NaN".
```

I don't really know what the issued might be here. There was another thread with the same error in which the problem was that the data was a string and not a number, but that doesn't seem to be an issue here. Basically I have two identical functions, so when I click the bars it should only change the color of the bars, However, the bars still go missing.
Here the code of the function (which is similar to the code that generates the chart when the page loads up):

```
function alter_show() {

d3.json("testV.json", function(data) {

var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height,1]);
var x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width]);

y.domain([1,d3.max(data,function(d) {return d.clients})]);
x.domain(data.map(function(d) {return d.ym}));

svg.select(".x.axis").call(d3.axisBottom(x))
svg.select(".y.axis").call(d3.axisLeft(y))


bar = svg.selectAll("rect")         

bar.data(data).enter().append("rect")
    .attr('class','bar')
    .attr("x", function (d) {return x(d.ym); })
    .attr("y", function (d) {return y(d.clients); })
    .attr("height", function (d) {return height - y(d.clients)})
    .attr("width", x.bandwidth()*0.5)
    .attr("color","black")
    .attr("transform",
      "translate(" + (margin.left + x.bandwidth()*0.25) + "," + margin.top + ")")
    .on('mouseenter', function() {
        d3.select(this).transition().duration(100).attr('opacity',0.5).attr('color', 'orange')})
    .on('mouseleave', function() {
        d3.select(this).transition().duration(100).attr('opacity',1)})
    .on('click',alter_show);


svg.append("g").selectAll("text").data(data).enter().append("text")
    .attr('class','value')
    .attr("x", function (d) {return x(d.ym); })
    .attr("y", function (d) {return y(d.trans); })
    .text(function (d) {return d.trans})
    .attr('font-size','0.7em')
    .attr("transform",
      "translate(" + (margin.left + x.bandwidth()*0.25)  + "," + (margin.top + 30) + ")");

bar.exit().remove();
  // updated data:
  bar.transition()
    .duration(750)
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return y(d.value);
    })
    .attr("height", function(d) {
      return height - y(d.value);
    })});}
```

So to sum it up, this function works when I load the page, but when I click the bars, it doesn't show the bars. Thanks for you help, let me know if there's any additional info you need :)

Comment: Your best bet will be clicking in chrome console on that error, and trying to find it's source. If you make a JSfiddle, maybe someone will take a look

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Where is the field `value` in your data?

```
bar.transition()
    .duration(750)
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); });
```

You have to fix all the other problems with the chart yourself.